# Python sqlite3 generate unique identifier

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to add values to a 'pending application table'. This is what I have so far:

```
    appdata = [(ID,UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER,(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),self.amount_input.get(),self.why_input.get())]

    self.c.execute('INSERT into Pending VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', appdata)
    self.conn.commit()
```

I need to set a value for 'UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER', which is a primary key in a sqlite database.

How can I generate a unquie number for this value?

```
CREATE TABLE Pending (
    ID          STRING REFERENCES StaffTable (ID),
    PendindID   STRING PRIMARY KEY,
    RequestDate STRING,
    Amount      TEXT,
    Reason      TEXT
);
```

Comment: Could you use an auto increment column for this purpose?

Comment: That would be good, I am new to sqlite and I am unsure how to do it correctly though

Comment: Please post your table structure.

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**two ways to do that:**

**1-First**

in python you can use `uuid` module example:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
'5f202bf198e24242b6a11a569fd7f028'
```

**note** ***: a small chance to get the same str so check for object exist with the same primary key in the table before saving***

this method `uuid.uuid4()` each time return new random

**for example:**

```
>>> ID=str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
>>>cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Pending WHERE PendindID = ?", (ID,))
>>>if len(data)==0:
      #then save new object as there is no row with the same id
   else:
       #create new ID
```

**2-second**

in `sqlite3` make a composite primary key according to sqlite [doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Pending (
  column1, 
  column2, 
  column3, 
  PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2)
);
```

Then make sure of uniqueness throw `unique(column1, column2)`

Comment: How can i generate a new id, then check if the id is already used?

Comment: thanks, that is a lot of help! But, can you explain what 'data' is. And, am i right to assume that if len(data)==0

Comment: If len(data) ==0, then the database search returned no IDs that matched to generated ID?

Comment: @MathewWright yes exactly data is the queryset if it's length zero the no ids matches generated id

Comment: @MathewWright you are welcome, mark the answer if it was correct .